# SQL 2008 Reporting Services "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

Tags: ssrs-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

SQl 2008 Reporting Services (SP1, CU4) installed on Windows 2008 R2. Service account is configured to use Network Service. Port 80 is open in the Firewall. Continue to get "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." error no matter what i try. Need advice on what else I can check or where I can look for any errors with more detail beside 503 error. I have tried turning on customerror but still cannot figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Anything in the windows event log? Have you created the ReportServer database and done all of the required setup and configuration? Is it the reporting services service running under that account? is it running? how about the SQL Server containing the ReportServer database?

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the SSRS service solved the issue for me. 
Environment: SSRS2016, Window Server 2012 R2 Standard

Answer (score 0):

Check the rsreportserver.config file

I had deleted the :443 in my file under the url bindings by accident and got this error.

```
<Application>
            <Name>ReportManager</Name>
            <VirtualDirectory>Reports</VirtualDirectory>
            <URLs>
                <URL>
                    <UrlString>http://+:80</UrlString>
                    <AccountSid>S-1-5-20</AccountSid>
                    <AccountName>NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE</AccountName>
                </URL>
                <URL>
                    <UrlString>https://xxx.xxx.net**:443**</UrlString>
                    <AccountSid>S-1-5-20</AccountSid>
                    <AccountName>NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE</AccountName>
                </URL>
                <URL>
                    <UrlString>http://xxx.xxx.com:80</UrlString>
                    <AccountSid>S-1-5-20</AccountSid>
                    <AccountName>NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE</AccountName>
                </URL>
            </URLs>
        </Application>

</URLReservations>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check IIS to see if the application pool that SSRS uses is running.
I've seen this error arise when the application pool has terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into SSRS logs on your server which is located at:

```
 %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\<SQL Server Instance>\Reporting Services\LogFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error and tried deleting the URL's from the rsreportserver.config file.
After lots of frustration, I found that the permissions on that file did not allow ReportServer user to modify the file.  Once I gave the reporting user permission on the file, all was good to remove / update URL's, and returned SSRS back into service.  Good luck!